Spring Boot 3 login page not loading properly
I have migrated my project from vaadin security to Spring Boot 3.When I try to access login page  through localhost:8080 console shows these messages.Before login page is properly load these message appears in logs.after putting credentials (user and Password) it doesnt not redirect to main page.
[nio-8080-exec-6] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Match found! Executing org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint@1abc3085
 [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
 [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
 [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
 [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login
 [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/login", parameters={}
 [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ParameterizableViewController [view="login"]
 [nio-8080-exec-7] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
 [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7]
 [nio-8080-exec-7] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
 [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
 [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/css/main.css", parameters={}
 [nio-8080-exec-8] nServletConfiguration$RootExcludeHandler : Mapped to org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController@51d2218e
 [nio-8080-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[springServlet]        : The response class [class org.springframework.security.web.firewall.FirewalledResponse] could not be unwraped to the Catalina response class and will be closed immediately after the forward
 [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
 [l-2 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-2 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
 [l-2 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-2 - Fill pool skipped, pool has sufficient level or currently being filled (queueDepth=0).
 [nio-8080-exec-9] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header

java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1288) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1176) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:785) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:348) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:264) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840) ~[na:na]`

[nio-8080-exec-9] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error state [CLOSE_CONNECTION_NOW] reported while processing request

java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1288) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1176) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:785) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:348) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:264) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840) ~[na:na]


Please provide
a MRE

Are you sure it was Vaadin security? What version of Vaadin? As I do not know Vaadin security products, there is the Vaadin AppSec Kit, or the SSO Kit, and other kits. Plus there are two frameworks Hilla and Flow (which will be combined soon in one of the next versions).
Could you please provide some more details on this question?

what do you mean by "I have migrated my project from vaadin security to Spring Boot 3." how did you do that? Show some code please

It was Vaadin version 23.
